# Is there a library that can give me all instances of a class which occur in another class?

Tags: java, reflection

I have a class which has several fields which are a subclass of another class. I want to quickly find all instances of that subclass within the top level class.

For example

```
public class TopClass {
 private ClassIWant1 myVar1;
 private ClassIWant2 myVar2;
 private OtherJunk myVar3;
 private Nested myVar4;
}

public class Nested {
 private ClassIWant3 myVar11;
}

public class SuperClass {
}

public ClassIWant1 extends SuperClass {}
public ClassIWant2 extends SuperClass {}
public ClassIWant3 extends ClassIWant1 {}
```

If I were to run that example through with an instance of `TopClass` I would expect to get a List containing the values for myVar1, myVar2, and myVar11.

I have a general idea of how to use reflection to do this manually, but I'm hoping that I don't have to reinvent the wheel. Is there a library that can do this?

I am familiar with [ReflectUtils](http://code.google.com/p/reflectutils/), but I am not sure if that can do this or not.

Comment: For reference, "quickly" and "with reflection" are...conflicting objectives, unless you're referring to "quickly" in the sense of "I will not have to write much code."

Comment: @LouisWasserman - Fair point. I mean the latter. I've made the decision to use reflection which is a performance penalty. If a general purpose library exists, I can at least save some maintenance and testing time by using that instead of writing and testing my own code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your request correctly, you're looking for something like this:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TopClass top = …; // initialise as appropriate
        System.out.println(findFields(top, SuperClass.class));
    }

    private static <T> List<T> findFields(Object haystack, Class<T> needle) {
        return findFields0(haystack, needle, new HashSet<Object>(), new ArrayList<T>());
    }

    private static <T> List<T> findFields0(Object haystack, Class<T> needle, Set<Object> visited, List<T> result) {
        if (visited.contains(haystack)) return result; // we already searched this object

        visited.add(haystack);

        for (Field field : haystack.getClass().getFields()) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Object fieldValue = null;
            try {
                fieldValue = field.get(haystack);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                // shouldn't happen
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            if (needle.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())) {
                result.add(needle.cast(fieldValue));
            }

            // recurse
            findFields0(fieldValue, needle, visited, result);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

This works by using the static types of the fields as declared. That is, if you declare a field as `Object` but it holds an instance of `SuperClass` or one of its descendants, it won't be found. It will also return `null`s if the fields have them set as the value. I have no idea what this will do about primitive types.

**Disclaimer:** Code was tested briefly on an optimistic example, I hold no responsibility if it causes your computer to catch fire.

Comment: I think this works, but I'm having to massage it a little to play nicely with Lists which hold instances of SuperClass.

Comment: This works well. Thank you! I had to add an else case to determine if the field type was a ParameterizedType then get the actual types and then if one of those types was assignable from needle add all the elements from fieldValue to result.

Answer (score -1):

Is [this method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredClasses%28%29) what you're looking for?

Comment: Is that recursive? I think that gives me the name of the class but not the value of a field for an instance.

Comment: I don't believe it is recursive but I don't imagine it would be difficult to write a method that calls this one recursively.

Comment: -1: 1) It's preferrable for answers to questions to actually exist on the site and not in its users' imaginations. 2) The method doesn't seem to be related to what the OP asked for. It will return the inner classes declared in the scope of a class, not values of its fields.